# How can I fix the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.contrib'"

Tags: python, scrapy

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.contrib'` in the scrapy console when trying to run my project.

I noticed that the python linter is underlining the line:

`from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule`

which seems like the error is occuring there.

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 1):

After reading some couple of articles I noticed that the scrapy.contrib module is deprecated and has been changed in the scrapy library.

The below changes made the fix for me:

**old import**: `from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule` to

**new import/upgraded import**: `from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule`

This is a complete resource to the [release note](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#deprecation-removals)

Answer (score 0):

> pip install scrapy-contrib-bigexporters

You can try this command to install scrapy library into anaconda prompt.